# angular directive sharing scope issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created one directive and I'm looping it.  The problem I'm having is that for some reason the $scope.name shows the name from the last directive even though I did an isolate scopes

```
angular.module("testApp")
 .controller("testingCtrl","$scope",function($scope)       {
     infos =[
     {
       name ="test1"
     },
     {
       name ="test2"
     }
     ]
     $scope.init=function(name){
        $scope.name=name
     }
 })
 .controller("directiveCtrl",["$scope",function($scope){
        console.log("HEY",$scope.name);
 }])
 .directive("testing",function(){
    return{
      restrict:"E",
      controller:"directiveCtrl",
      scope:{
        name:"="
      },
      template:"<h1>{{name}}</h1>"
  }
})
<div ng-app="testApp">
   <div ng-controller="testingCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="info in infos" ng-init="init(info.name)">
         <testing name="name"></testing>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

so it's showing

test2

test2

but what I want is

test1

test2

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why are you creating an object to pass in as the name?

Comment: hi @dwbartz i'm trying to replicate the scenario in a more shorter and easier to read code since the real one is much more bigger and it won't fit here.

Comment: Get rid of ng-init and that init function. Playing with scope is bad.

Comment: @luis I was talking about you passing in an object into the attribute as a parameter for you directive. Looks like you fixed it though.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why yours was having those issues, but when trying to replicate your problem I made a codepen with the following changes as I assume you didn't copy your working Angular code exactly:

- Set `ng-repeat` to `info in infos` *(yours wasn't working)*
- Pass `info.name` to the directive instead of `{name:info.name}`

These changes caused it to output

```
test1
test2
```

Here's my codepen:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JRKyAK?editors=1010#0

**Edit:**
With the edits you've made, you have a different problem.

The reason you are seeing `test2` repeated, is because you are calling `init(info.name)` in your `ng-init` for each `info` in `infos`, as that init function is invoked each time Angular generates one of those new divs.
The problem with that, is that `$scope.init` is overwriting `$scope.name` every time `ng-repeat` generates a new info div. This is what is causing your last element to always be displayed, as your directive is being passed `$scope.name` which will always contain your last element's name.

I'd suggest not using `ng-init`, and rather pass info attributes such as name directly into your directive like so:

```
<testing name="info.name"></testing>
```

Comment: sorry @Amaan M , i forgot to add the rest of it, i just edit the post